# How to describe precompact subsets in $L^1$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Recall that a precompact subset is a subset whose closure is compact and a compact operator is a linear operator who maps bounded subsets to precompact subsets.

In my analysis course, my teacher left us the following question.

*Question.* Let $K:[a,b]^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous, where $a <b$. Define an operator $T:L^1 \to L^1$ by $$Tf(x)=\int_a^bK(x,y)f(y)dy.$$
Show that $T$ is a compact operator.

My idea is to check as definition above, but it seems hard for me to describe precompact subsets in  $L^1$, and I can just find the discriptions for the case of $C[a,b],L^p (p>1)$. I wonder whether there is a description in the case of $L^1$ or shall I change my idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know this operator to be compact on $L^2$ from my course (a long time ago) on Hilbert space operators. The [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator) has some alternative formulations of the definition, which might help?

Comment: Observe that $T$ maps $L^1(a,b)$ to  $C[a,b].$ Call this operator by $T_0.$ Then $T_0$  is compact. For that you can show that the family of functions $T_0f,$ with $\|f\|_1\le 1,$ is equicontinuous and bounded. Then by Arzeli-Ascoli theorem the  family is compact. Now $T=J\circ T_0,$ where $J$ denotes the inclusion mapping from $C[a,b]$ into $L^1(a,b).$

Comment: Would the Stone-Weierstrass theorem help?  $K$ is uniformly approximable on $[a,b]^2$ by polynomials $K_n$ in $x$ and $y$, and for such kernels the corresponding operators on $L^1$ would have finite rank.

Comment: Nice idea and I will try it, thanks!@BazyliZuczek

Comment: Stone-Weierstrass proposed by leslie townes is a nice idea, too

Answer (score 1):

The conditions for pre compactness in $L^p$ ($p \in [1,\infty)$) is given by the  Fréchet–Kolmogorov theorem (see [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fréchet–Kolmogorov_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet%E2%80%93Kolmogorov_theorem)). One can think of it as a kind of Arzela--Ascoli theorem for $L^p$.